# Any textbook on elementary real analysis that has many and good exercises?

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

I'm currently undertaking a first course in Real Analysis. My course uses the textbook Understanding Analysis by Stephen Abbott.

The textbook is readable for my level but it does not come with many exercises.

Anyone knows of a similar textbook or other resource that provides plenty of good exercises?

I'm going to use it just for the exercises.

Comment: Read from Abbott, solve from Rudin.

Comment: I love Spivak's calculus.

Comment: Did you have a look at other questions tagged [real-analysis+book-recommendation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-analysis+book-recommendation)?

Comment: @MartinSleziak yes, but they didn't compare the exercises of the books

Comment: @LandonCarter i have read that the baby Rudin is difficult for people starting on the first real analysis course.

Comment: @yh05 I don't know, I started from Rudin itself. Of course I had a very nice professor.

Comment: @LandonCarter Good for you! can i get some real analysis related resource from you?

Answer (score 1):

I warmly recommend:

Tom M. Apostol: Mathematical Analysis (Addison- Wesley)

Comment: I shall take a look at the exercises.

Answer (score 1):

You can find  lot of interesting problems in the book ' Real mathematical analysis ' by C C Pugh. Even the book is quite good in its approach towards subject. 
Also, I like to recommend the book 'Real Analysis'  by N L Carothers .

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently self-studying introductory real analysis and am using Numbers and Functions: Steps into Analysis by R. P. Burn.

I have tried other books before but since I am not very experienced with rigorous mathematics I couldn't find something at my level. Numbers and Functions is a great book which I am making progress with. The whole book is just problems and focuses on guiding you to build up the theory.

It also comes with solutions to almost every single problem. This is invaluable for someone like me relying on the book for the majority of instruction. It makes checking progress easy and prevents any big misunderstandings.

Comment: Thanks. will take a look at the content of the book

Comment: @user21820 I wrote this at the beginning of the year. Things have progressed a lot since then. :) Would be interested in any notes you have regardless.

Comment: @shredalert Did you read any other book after this one to follow up with Analysis?